# webpack での jquery の $ 変数の扱いについて

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

[jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/download/) と [jquery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) を同時に使いたいのですがうまくいきません

どちらも $ っていう変数に対してメソッドを追加してるんだと思うんですが片方を使うともう片方が使えなくなります

---

jquery-ui は公式サイトダウンロードビルダーから zip ダウンロードしたものを
app/javascript/vendor/jquery-ui
に展開

jquery.validationEngine は
app/javascript/vendor/jquery.validationEngine
に clone してあります

---

**config/webpack/environment.js　をデフォルトのまま**
application.js に

```
globalThis.jQuery = globalThis.$ = require('jquery');
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css'
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'
```

とかくと $.slider() が動きますが

```
import '../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/jquery.validationEngine';
```

を追加すると

```
jquery.validationEngine.js:2163 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object../app/javascript/vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/jquery.validationEngine.js (jquery.validationEngine.js:2163)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

と jQuery が見つからないというエラーになります

globalThis.jQuery　=　に代入しているにもかかわらず
なぜそのあとの import で jQuery がみつからなくなるんでしょうか

---

一方で config/webpack/environment.js に

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
);
```

をかくと application.js で

```
import '../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/jquery.validationEngine';
```

をしてもエラーが出なくなるんですが

```
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css'
```

もかいてるにもかかわらず $.slider(); で

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

となってしまいます

---

**追記:**

[Rails6 webpacker から bootstrap js を使う方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83006/rails6-webpacker-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-bootstrap-js-%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%86%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

ProvidePlugin を記述するとこちらで教えていただいた bootstrap の JS も
jquery-ui に関係なく （jquery-ui関連のインポートを全部消しても)

`$(...).modal is not a function`

で動かなくなってしまいました

---

[Rails + webpacker における global と window と config/webpack/environment.js の違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83118/rails-webpacker-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-global-%e3%81%a8-window-%e3%81%a8-config-webpack-environment-js-%e3%81%ae%e9%81%95%e3%81%84)

最近こちらの質問をみかけたんですが
globalThis と ProvidePlugin でなぜ挙動がかわってしまうんでしょうか

ProvidePlugin があまり理解できてないなくてこれまではなしで動いていたので
できれば ProvidePlugin を使わずに globalThis だけで
jQuery-Validation-Engine を動かしたいのですが方法はないでしょうか

---

今の application.js がこんな感じで
ここに validation engine を追加しようとしました

```
import Rails from '@rails/ujs'
globalThis.Rails = Rails
Rails.start()

require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import * as jquery from 'jquery'
globalThis.jQuery = globalThis.$ = jquery;

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
globalThis.bootstrap = bootstrap

// // jQuery-Validation-Engine
// import '../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/jquery.validationEngine';
// // require('../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-ja');
// import '../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en';

/* Validate form */
// $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
//   $("form").validationEngine();
// });

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all';

import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css'
import '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'

import * as moment from 'moment'
globalThis.moment = moment

import '../stylesheets/application.scss';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コードの順番に関係無く、`import`や`require`でモジュールのファイルを読み込む処理が最初に実行され、その後に地の文にある処理が実行されるからです。

どういうことかというと、`import '../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/jquery.validationEngine';`の方が、`globalThis.jQuery = globalThis.$ = jquery;`での代入の処理より前に実行されてしまいます。そのため、jquery.validationEngineの中身が実行される時点ではグローバル変数`jQuery`が用意されておらず、変数が見つからないとして、実行に失敗するとなっています。逆に、ProvidePluginがうまくいくのは、`import`の処理の前にProvidePluginの処理が実行されるので、グローバル変数`jQuery`が用意されているというわけです。

jQuery UIが何故うまくいくというと、jQuery UIのコードにはAMDに対応する部分があり、webpackがそれを考慮して、jQueryがモジュールとして読み込まれていれば、そのjQueryに対して設定するという動きになっているからです。(詳しくは調べていませんが、ProvidePluginだとおかしくなるのは、このあたりが原因かもしれません。ProviderPluginで読み込まれたjQueryとimportされたjQueryが別の物扱いで、追加のメソッドが設定されないという物です。bootstrapもjQueryをimportすると言った動作だったはずなので、そちらもそれが原因でしょう。)

では、どうすればいいのかというと、ファイルを分けます。下記内容のjquery-validation-engine.jsを用意します。

```
import '../vendor/jQuery-Validation-Engine/js/jquery.validationEngine';
```

これをapplicationの後に読む込むようにします。application.html.erbは次のようになるでしょう。

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'jquery-validation-engine', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

これで、うまくいくはずです。

---

この方法には注意事項があります。まもなく正式リリースされるwebpacker 6系では複数のJavaScirptに分割することをサポートしていません。全てのJavaScriptは`application.js`一つにまとめておく必要があり、この方法は使えなくなります。

一つのファイルにまとめるにはどうするのかですが、[Upgrading from Webpacker 5 to 6](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v6_upgrade.md)に次のヒントが書いてありました。

> If you expose jquery globally with `expose-loader`, by using `import $ from "expose-loader?exposes=$,jQuery!jquery"` in your `app/javascript/application.js`, pass the option `efer: false` to your `javascript_pack_tag`.

この方法はwebpacker 5系でも使えます。実際に使ってみましょう。まずは、`yarn add expose-loader@1`として、expose-loaderをインストールします(webpacker 5系はwebpack 4系を使用するため、expose-loderは1系を使う必要があり、`@1`を付けるようにしてください)。そして、jQueryの部分を次のように書きます。(最新のexpose-loader 3系とは書き方が異なるので注意してください。)

```
import $ from "expose-loader?exposes[]=$&exposes[]=jQuery!jquery";
```

こうすると、jQueryの`import`処理と同時にexpose-loaderがグローバル変数にセットしてくれるようです。`import`処理同士は順番に実行されるため、jquery.validationEngineが読み込まれるときには、グローバル変数`jQuery`が存在することになりうまくいくという仕組みです。

---

そもそもの問題はjQuery.validationEngineが現代的なモジュールベースに対応した物としてかかれていないと言うことです。jQuery UIの開発も終了しており、Bootstrapも5系からjQuery依存が無くなったと言うこともありますので、将来的にはjQueryには依存しない方向にシフトしていった方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: 丁寧にわかりやすい説明ありがとうございます。import や require がコード順にかかわらず先に実行されるのを知りませんでした。
jquery-ui の node_module 以下をみてると中に jquery 本体があってそれで２重定義で上書きされちゃってるのかなと勝手に思っていました。
おかげさまで view で分割して動いたんですが jquery-ui 自体更新とまるということで slider だけしか使ってないので別のライブラリを使ってみることにします。Rails の場合 render js: $().modal みたいな JS view が使うときれいにかけるケースがあってグローバルでメソッド定義しておきたいけど定義の仕方が分からなかったので本当に助かります

Comment: 役に立てて幸いです。第3の方法としてexpose-loaderを使う方法を追加してますので、こちらも参考にしてみてください。